# How to add non-linear constraints to ortools

Tags: python, or-tools

How to add non-linear constraints to ortools
It is said that the AddMultiplicationEquality() method can be used to add non-linear constraints, but I don't know how to use it.

```
for n in all_nurses:
    for s in all_shifts:
        shifts[(n, s)] = model.NewBoolVar('shift_n%id%i' % (n, s))
for n in all_nurses:
    model.AddMultiplicationEquality(sum(shifts[(n, s1[0])] * shifts[(n,s1[1])] * TC[s1[0]][s1[1]] for s1 in all_shifts1) == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed in:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/or-tools-discuss/0CPlgg4eHn8

If you cross-post, please indicate where you cross-posted.

Thansk